# Find files with certain text within certain date range

Tags: command-line, files, find

I have a folder with huge number of files and I want to extract files present with certain text XYZ created within a date range.

I found this to search files within a date range, but unsure how to club it with the specific text filter.

```
find /MY_DIR/ -newermt "2017-12-01" ! -newermt "2021-01-31"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to add an `-exec` option.

```
find /MY_DIR/ -type f -newermt "2017-12-01" ! -newermt "2021-01-31" -exec grep -l XYZ {} +
```

Also added `-type f` option to only look for regular files, not directories, sockets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to find some text within those files just use `grep`
like this:

```
grep -i "XYZ" `find /MY_DIR/ -newermt "2017-12-01" ! -newermt "2021-01-31"`
```

The `-i` switch makes it case insensitive.

The `grep` at the start of the line will look for text in files.